# Обособление оборота с "как"

Tags: пунктуация, как

Заголовок: "Здесь людям хорошим как солнышку рады". Нужно ли в данном случае обособлять оборот "как солнышку"? Меня терзают сомнения(

Answer (score 2):

**Здесь людям хорошим, как солнышку, рады.**

Сравнительный оборот (*как солнышку*), начинающийся союзом *как*, должен отделяться запятыми. Возможно, Ваши сомнения вызваны тем, что оборот предшествует сказуемому, и тем, что существительное в обороте стоит не в именительном падеже. На самом деле это не отменяет правила.

Примеры:

Вокруг высокого чела, как тучи, локоны чернеют (Пушкин).

Внизу, как зеркало стальное, синеют озера струи (Тютчев).

Я через всю свою жизнь, как через тысячу лет, пронес это воспоминание (Пришвин).

Как невесту, родину мы любим, бережем, как ласковую мать (Лебедев-Кумач).

См. [§ 115 Сравнительный оборот](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Расположение и падеж меня не смутили, первая мысль была - отделять, конечно, ведь это обычный сравнительный оборот. А потом вдруг стало казаться, что он чересчур сильно связан со сказуемым, и тут понеслось... Приведённые Вами примеры сомнения рассеивают, ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Розенталь поясняет, что если оборот по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым, то обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не имеет законченного смысла без этого сравнительного оборота. А у вас остается смысл вполне законченный и после удаления этого оборота: *Здесь людям хорошим рады.*

Answer (score 0):

Допускаются оба варианта, они имеют различную интонацию и разные логические ударения.

1) **Здесь людям хорОшим, как сОлнышку, рАды.**  Главная мысль: рады хорошим людям, попутное сравнение: рады как солнышку.

Структура предложения (порядок слов) не очень удобна для прочтения, а содержание не выражает особых эмоций.

2) **Здесь лЮдям хорошим как сОлнышку рады.** Главная мысль – это выразить степень чувства:  очень рады. Здесь  слово **рады** тонического ударения не имеет, а  вот нужная  пара **людям – солнышку** логически выделена

Второй вариант **более эмоционален** и соответствует разговорной речи. Кроме того, он более удобен для чтения (оно  легкое, естественное, без напряжения голоса).

Comment: Интонационно, согласна, не выделяется, произносится как единое выражение. Наверное, поэтому я и начала сомневаться с обособлением.

Comment: Правила позволяют не обособлять такие обороты. У Розенталя:4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом как не выделяется запятыми:
1) если на первый план выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия; Как зарницы в небе они запылали, как огненный дождь с неба упали; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147 Ясно, что здесь тоже ударение падает на оборот, он не отделяется паузой от сказуемого, а это и есть тесная интонационная связь

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы видите здесь тот случай, когда, по словам Розенталя "на первый план в обороте выступает значение обстоятельства образа действия (на вопрос как?)". Как рады? - Как солнышку - это кажется немного натянутым.

Comment: У Розенталя проще: запылали зарницами, упали дождем. А у нас что? Рады "радостью наблюдающего за  солнцем"? Не очень убедительно, на мой взгляд...

Comment: Мы с главным редактором решили выделить оборот запятыми. Спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: Вы пользуетесь исключительно смысловым принципом интонации и совершенно забываете   о  структурно-интонационном. Какие там подстановки, о чем Вы! В предложении одно слово уберешь, и в нем уже равновесие нарушится, другие знаки препинания надо ставить. Тесная смысловая связь оборота со сказуемым бывает необходима по смыслу (об этом говорит Розенталь) , но выражается она тесной интонационной связью - отсутствием паузы и логическим ударением на обороте. Не важно, какие конкретно примеры Розенталь приводит, но важно ПОНЯТЬ ИХ СУТЬ, а не использовать какие-то формальные подстановки и сравнения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, Наталья. В конце концов, вы же не Лермонтова редактируете, а обычный пользователь предпочитает  обособленные сравнительные обороты во всех случаях. Вот к такой реформе правописания мы. возможно, когда-нибудь и придем, да и классика тоже отредактируем.

Comment: Вы правы, Arina, простому читателю районной газеты обособление будет понятней. У меня сомнения остались, поэтому окончательное решение оставила за главным редактором. Редактор решила, что лучше обособлять, чем не обособлять. А мои стенания, видимо, продолжатся(

Comment: Arina, насколько я понимаю, вопрос о постановке запятых в принципе непростой, и есть две школы: сторонники грамматического принципа и сторонники интонационного. Не будучи профессионалом в этой области, не беру на себя смелость судить :)

Comment: Я думаю, что никаких школ нет, интонацию стали чаще упоминать в грамматических учебниках, но не в учебниках по правописанию. Но одно ясно: не учитывая интонацию, мы получаем формально правильное, но фактически неправильное решение, как, например, в данном случае. По своему определению, знаки препинания - это паузы, на которые мы делим речь,  Вот вы обособили оборот, обозначили паузы, а в устной речи их нет, и предложение звучит "фальшиво", неправильно, невыразительно. Кому нужны такие знаки препинания!